# Multiple Ionic HTTP calls

Tags: angular, ionic3

I need some advice on my code! 
I am new on Ionic and Angular!

So, use 2 HttpClient request on single page, **and sometimes, one of them does not recieve the response**!

How to be sure, all my httpget request will recieve the response 100%?

P.S. All my HTTP get calls going from provider.

P.S.S Sory for my bad english, hope moderator will correct it!
My code is like this:

**1st Call**

```
getUserInfo() {
    return this.rest.getUserInfo(URL).then( data => {
        this.userInfo = data;
    })
}
```

**2nd Call**

```
getUserLevels() {
    return this.rest.getUserLevels(URL).then( data => {
        this.levelInfo = data;
    })
}
```

So at the end, into the ionviewdidenter, i have put this function, like:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.getUserInfo();
    this.getUserLevels();
}
```

Comment: what backend is your API?

Comment: I am using rest API! I have Ultimate Memebership Plugin, that make some API gate! From that API, i recieve response, and convert it into object! And result from object into ionic app!

Comment: lol. :) I meant what technology(s) are you using on your API? (ASP.NET Web API, NodeJs)

Comment: Im using nodejs....sry!

Comment: no problem. Why do you say "and sometimes, one of them does not receive the response"? Have you added logging to check that responses are not received?

Comment: result from this calls, are user info and user level! And when i put this result into Ionic app, sometimes, i have undefined response from one of them! But, if i refresh the page, or going to another page and return, its all Ok! Looks like, http request does not wiating for response!

Comment: And, yes, the console.log show me sometimes = undefined! If i refresh the page, all is fine!

Comment: update your provider ??

Comment: Are you using console.log in the result of promise ? ( .then( data => { // there }); ) .

Comment: Yes, iam using console.log(), and as i said, recieve undefined!